# How to parse a comma delimited string into seperate rows but ignore the comma for certain values

Tags: sql-server

We have a comma delimited string

```
"col1=xyz,col2=mno,col3=ABC,ZZZ,col4=complete"
```

So, the desired result needs to be:

```
col1 xyz
col2 mno
col3 ABC,ZZZ
col4 complete
```

When I try to parse this is what happens (col4 get split as it had a comma)

```
col1 xyz
col2 mno
**col3 ABC
col4 ZZZ**
col4 complete
```

What's the best way to get this into the desired result using SQL?

Comment: Do you have any limit in number of `col's` ?. How the string is generated. Better to fix while generating string by using different delimiter

Comment: Does the value to the left of the equals always have a known format or prefix?  If they literally always start with "col#" then read until you hit one of those followed by an equal sign, chop it off the end and everything left of it is the prior row's "value" or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeList varchar(max)) 
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'col1=xyz,col2=mno,col3=ABC,ZZZ,col4=complete'),
(2,'emp_id="123",emp_status="New Hire",emp_name="Smith, John A"')

;with cte as (
      Select A.ID,B.*
      From  @YourTable A
      Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](Replace(A.SomeList,' ','|'),',') B
)
Select A.ID
      ,Col_Name = left(A.RetVal,charindex('=',A.RetVal)-1)
      ,Value    = replace(substring(replace(A.RetVal + case when charIndex('=',B.RetVal)>0 then '' else ','+B.RetVal end,'|',' '),charindex('=',A.RetVal)+1,len(B.RetVal)+len(A.RetVal)),'"','')
 From  cte A
 Left  Join cte B on A.ID=B.ID and A.RetSeq=B.RetSeq-1 
 Where B.RetVal is not null and charIndex('=',A.RetVal)>0
 Order By ID,A.RetSeq
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Col_Name    Value
1   col1        xyz
1   col2        mno
1   col3        ABC,ZZZ
2   emp_id      123
2   emp_status  New Hire
2   emp_name    Smith, John A
```

**The UDF if Needed**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ replace((Select @String as [*] For XML Path('')),@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

Comment: I got it to work and I have another similar comma delimited string so when I try to do the CROSS APPLY second time in the same query I believe I am getting double counts

Comment: @SQLUser Need to see your data

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't.
The long answer is: you can, if you 1) choose a different delimiter that will not appear in your strings - how about semicolon or dollar sign? or 2) define an escape-character that means "the character after this should be parsed differently than it normally would", but I'm not sure if that's doable in your context, or 3) stop using CSV and use fixed width fields, eg: field1 is always 10 characters, etc, then no delimiter needed

Comment: Select A.ID
      ,Col_Name = left(B.RetVal,charindex('=',B.RetVal)-1)
      ,Value    = Replace(Substring(B.RetVal,charindex('=',B.RetVal)+1,Len(B.RetVal)),'"','')
   ,Col_Name2 = left(C.RetVal,charindex('=',C.RetVal)-1)
      ,Value2    = Replace(Substring(C.RetVal,charindex('=',C.RetVal)+1,Len(C.RetVal)),'"','')
 From  @YourTable A 
CROSS APPLY (select A.SomeList )B
Cross Apply (Select A.SomeList2 )C

Comment: So, I have 2 big columns that are comma delimited and I need to do the same step..so was trying to do the CROSS APPLY twice and I believe I am getting a double count

Comment: String_New_Value = emp_id=123,emp_status="Full Time",'emp_name='Smith, John A"

String_Old_Value=emp_id=123,emp_status="New Hire",emp_name="Smith, John A"

So, we need to parse both the columns into their respective Column Name & Value

So, we would need to have 4 new columns
String_To_Value would be parsed to :
String_To_Column_Name (Showing the column Name)
String_To_Value (Showing the Value)

Likewise, String_Old_Value would be parsed to

Comment: Likewise, String_Old_Value would be parsed to 
String_Old_Column_Name (Parsing the column Name)
String_Old_Value (Parsing the value)

Comment: (1,'col1=xyz,col2=mno,col3=ABC,ZZZ,col4=complete'),
(2,'emp_id="123",emp_status="New Hire",emp_name="Smith, John A",emp_salary=2000') 
Doesn't split the emp_salary...it just doesn't see it

Comment: (1,'emp_id="123",emp_status="New Hire",emp_name="Smith, John A",emp_salary=2000,emp_state="VA"')
It fetches until emp_salary but fails to fetch emp_state=VA